# jQuery - hide() e show() não é executado corretamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

Eu tenho itens do qual em um parágrafo é exibido o total dos mesmos. Quando eu removo um desses itens, eu estou trabalhando com 2 parágrafos com o mesmo código para que eu esconda um e mostre o outro, para que possa exibir o valor correto. Porém, quando eu clico no botão que é para fazer essa função, somente um deles é alterado, enquanto o outro continua com o código original.

**Código dos parágrafos:**

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_index=>$_item): ?>
<p class="number" id="numberOriginal"><?php echo $this->__('Item %d of %d', $_index+1, $this->countItems()) ?></p>
<p class="number" id="numberModificado" style="display: none;"><?php echo $this->__('Item %d of %d', $_index+1, $this->countItems()-1) ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Código que "aciona" essa função:**

```
$j('input[name=isgift]').click(function(){
  if($j('#isgift1').is(':checked')){
  mudarNumber();
  }
});
```

**Código da função para alterar os `<p>`:**

```
function mudarNumber(){
  $j('#numberOriginal').hide();
  $j('#numberModificado').show();
}
```

**Exemplo:**

Item 1 dessa lista o `<p>` fica dessa maneira:

```
<p class="number" id="numberOriginal" style="display: none;">Item 1 de 3</p>
<p class="number" id="numberModificado" style="">Item 1 de 2</p>
```

Item 2 dessa lista o `<p>` fica dessa maneira:

```
<p class="number" id="numberOriginal">Item 2 de 3</p>
<p class="number" id="numberModificado" style="display: none;">Item 2 de 2</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente mudar o código *acionador* da função por:

```
$j('input[name=isgift]').on('click', function () {
  if ($j('#isgift1').is(':checked')) {
    $j('.numberOriginal').hide();
    $j('.numberModificado').show();
  }
});
```

E o código PHP, mude para:

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_index=>$_item): ?>
  <p class="number numberOriginal"><?php echo $this->__('Item %d of %d', $_index+1, $this->countItems()) ?></p>
  <p class="number numberModificado" style="display: none;"><?php echo $this->__('Item %d of %d', $_index+1, $this->countItems()-1) ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Desse modo, você poderá descartar esse pedaço de código:

```
function mudarNumber(){
  $j('#numberOriginal').hide();
  $j('#numberModificado').show();
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda! :D